# Angular caching index.html for one specific url

Tags: iis, http-caching

This is weirdest it can get. I did a fresh deployment of my Angular application with all new hashed js files.

Expectation is to get new files from server including html, css, js.

It is working fine except for one url where it switches back to older version of index.html from cache which then pulls older js files from cache.

I have been trying to fix this, but I couldn't find any solution.

I have already added these files in html file

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

And this in web.config

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0" />
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
    <add name="Expires" value="0" />
  </customHeaders>
```

But no effect of these changes.

Comment: can you be more descriptive about which url getting cached?

Comment: You are talking about get url of some api? provide more details.

Comment: Its Angular url, not api., There is one path to which when I route, it gets cached index.html

Comment: stackblitz please?

Comment: Its cache issue, how can I reproduce it in stackblitz!

Comment: have same code in stackblitz and tell me url for which its reproducing that behavior. or give me git repo url? Which reproducing or proper details, can't help in this

Comment: well, it is the webserver issue. It doesn't seem to be related to Angular. Cache headers are the issue. They could be provided by the web server (you use IIS I guess), CDN, or intermediate network infrastructure. You might start an investigation from Headers you receive in the browser. And proper tags to the issue would be of help (:

Comment: Have you tried to disable static compression and clean browser cache?

Comment: I wanted to find out without clearing cache, but yeah that was the last resort.

Comment: @DheerajKumar If browser cache is the root cause. Then there is no way to fix this on server side. Its just pure client side operation while cache always have the highest priority.

Answer (score 0):

Cache issue is related to the server not from the angular. Please look into the server configuration and headers which you are receiving in any request and you can try changing accordingly in the server configuration file till issue resolved.